# Can Magento 2 Site Be Put In An Iframe

Tags: magento2

Can Magento be emebdded in an iframe? Is there any surprises I should know about?

Thanks!

-Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on a project that essentially iframed in a Magento 1 shop to another website.

We ran into a fair few problems with cross-domain cookies (especially in Internet Explorer) and issues with the payment pages (as some of these are getting iframed in themself).

The design also needed heavily modified as to not completely break the flow and get a customer stuck somewhere on site.

As anectdotal as this answer is, I wouldn't really reccomend it.